# Find out the pairwise prime integer solutions?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, problem-solving

Number of pairwise prime positive integer solutions of $(x,y,z)$ in the equation
$$(1/x^2) + (1/y^2) = (1/z^2)$$

---

I had started the problem with taking numbers but unsuccessful to reach towards solution. Is there any general way to reach solution with ease!

Answer (score 3):

Note that we have
$$
\frac1{x^2}+\frac1{y^2}=\frac1{z^2}\iff (xz)^2+(yz)^2=(xy)^2
$$
so $z\mid xy$.  But we want $x,y,z$ pairwise coprime, so $z=1$.  Thus we have $x^2y^2=x^2+y^2$, or equivalently, $(x^2-1)(y^2-1)=1$ which has no solutions in $\mathbb{Z}^+$.

Comment: Sorry, what is meant by z| xy ?

Comment: $z$ divides $xy$.

Comment: @Sil that is not pairwise coprime --- $\gcd(x,y)=5\neq 1$ for example.

Comment: Oh right, obviously, i have looked at something else (corresponding pythagorean triple is pairwise coprime)